# get the local json server data in my ember application

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js, ember-data

I have created an one page web application using ember js. And I have installed the json.server in my local and created an json file(db.json). I really don't know how I can access my json.server in my application. I have used $.getJSON method and specified the json server URL http://localhost:3000/db.json(were my json server is running). But Its not any returning data. Please somebody give any suggestion of how I can access,edit my json file with ember js. 
Thanks in advance,

Comment: "Its not any returning data." — What is it doing? Use the developer tools in your browser. Is the statement being evaluated at all? Does it throw an error in the Console? Do you see the request being made in the Net tab? Does it get the response you expect? Have you added a jQuery error handler to the Ajax call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to request your `db.json` file directly. Json-server sets up RESTful API based on your `db.json` structure. Please take a look at the official example: https://github.com/typicode/json-server#example. Also please make sure that no other services is binded to `localhost:80` (json-server) launches with no errors.

Comment: Hi a.smirnov, Thanks for the reply. This is the exact thing I am looking for. Thanks a lot for saving my day. :-)